# Media Query Border Length

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Below is the code that I am using, but when using media queries for iPAD the right border is very close to the second Div , I want to have the border to appear align properly for all devices using media queries also for all browsers?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-6 large-6 columns right-border">
<h4>ABC TEST</h4>

<p>I love coding</p>
<p><strong>Code</strong></p>

</div>
<div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
<h4>ABC TEST</h4>

<p>Love coding</p>
  <p>live life</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div.right-border:before {
  content: "";
  border-right:1px solid #bcb4b4;
  width:60%;
  position:absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 90px;
  height: 80%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 760px) { 
div.right-border:before { 
border-right:none;
border-bottom:1px solid #ca6e6e; 
left:1%;
width:260px;
bottom:90%;
height:90%;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same selector in the media query that you used in the code above it: `div.right-border:before` (not `after`)

Comment: Thank you , I changed it to before. I am using media queries but when I test for ipad version the right border is very close to the second div . I need to allign the border with media queries and browsers.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you saying. Your question was about a bottom border, your comment is about a right border, and the codepen you just linked to in your previous comment didn't contain *any*  border. You should post complete code IN your question that clearly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This still isn't complete code. Just paste it into a snippet, a codepen or whatever, and you see what I mean. The CSS of the classes you use are not included. Maybe those are classes from some framework, but if yes, you didn't  mention which one.